# ValueAnimator не выполняется UpdateListener

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

я создаю аниматор и запускаю следующим образом

```
val va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f)
    va!!.addUpdateListener {
        object : ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
            override fun onAnimationUpdate(p0: ValueAnimator?) {
                Log.i("VVV", "LLL")
            }
        }
    }
    va.duration = 200
    va.start()
```

но не получаю в логах сообщений, при этом если добавить к примеру слушатель об окончании анимации, то он срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас на каждом шаге аниматора создается объект класса ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener, и никуда не складывается. Фигурные скобки говорят о регулярном выражении, т.к. параметр только один, то к нему можно обратиться как it. Либо замените фигурные на круглые, тогда у вас создается один раз объект листенера и отправится в аниматор, который будет его вызывать каждый шаг, или уберите лишние строки для создания объекта, и будет так

```
val va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f)
    va!!.addUpdateListener {
        Log.i("VVV", "LLL")
    }
    va.duration = 200
    va.start()
```

Comment: спасибо, это решило мою проблему